# creating a square matrix from a data frame

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I'm having trouble to make from my data.frame a square matrix. 
Now my data looks something like this:

```
  var1 var2 value
    A    B     4
    C    D     5 
    D    A     2
    B    D     1
```

I'm trying to transform the data.frame to a matrix that looks like this:

```
    A    B    C   D
  A 0    4    0   2
  B 4    0    0   1
  C 0    0    0   5
  D 2    1    5   0
```

I tried many functions from the different package available in R but still cannot find a solution.

Comment: Please post those many functions that you have tried and why it didn't work

Comment: `xtabs(value~var1+var2, df)` ?

Comment: @Sotos this would miss column `C`

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me.
@PoGibas I tried this:

`comatrix <- data.frame(var1 = data3$u1.var1, scores = data3$value, var2= factor(data3$var2,levels=unique(data3$var2)))
acast(comatrix, formula = var1 ~ var2, fill = 0, value.var ="scores", fun.aggregate =sum, drop = FALSE)`
By this code I got a matrix but not square one

Answer (score 8):

Here is a base R method using matrix indexing on character vectors.

```
## set up storage matrix
# get names for row and columns
nameVals <- sort(unique(unlist(dat[1:2])))
# construct 0 matrix of correct dimensions with row and column names
myMat <- matrix(0, length(nameVals), length(nameVals), dimnames = list(nameVals, nameVals))

# fill in the matrix with matrix indexing on row and column names
myMat[as.matrix(dat[c("var1", "var2")])] <- dat[["value"]]
```

This returns

```
myMat
  A B C D
A 0 4 0 0
B 0 0 0 1
C 0 0 0 5
D 2 0 0 0
```

For details on how this powerful form of indexing works, see the *Matrices and arrays* section of the help file `?"["`. In particular, the fourth paragraph of the section discusses this form of indexing.

Note that I assume that the first two variables are character vectors rather then factors. This makes it a bit easier, since I don't have to use `as.character` to coerce them.

To convert the result to a data.frame, simply wrap the above code in the `as.data.frame` function.

**data**

```
dat <- 
structure(list(var1 = c("A", "C", "D", "B"), var2 = c("B", "D", 
"A", "D"), value = c(4L, 5L, 2L, 1L)), .Names = c("var1", "var2", 
"value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 5):

If we make all the character columns `factor`s with levels 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' then we can use `xtabs` without dropping any columns.

Unfortunately, the resulting matrix isn't symmetric.

```
library('tidyverse')

df <- tribble(
  ~var1, ~var2, ~value,
    'A',   'B',      4,
    'C',   'D',      5,
    'D',   'A',      2,
    'B',   'D',      1
)

df %>%
  mutate_if(is.character, factor, levels=c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')) %>%
  xtabs(value ~ var1 + var2, ., drop.unused.levels = F)
#     var2
# var1 A B C D
#    A 0 4 0 0
#    B 0 0 0 1
#    C 0 0 0 5
#    D 2 0 0 0
```

To make it symmetric, I just added its transpose to itself. This feels like a bit of a hack, though.

```
df %>%
  mutate_if(is.character, factor, levels=c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')) %>%
  xtabs(value ~ var1 + var2, ., drop.unused.levels = F) %>%
  '+'(., t(.))
#     var2
# var1 A B C D
#    A 0 4 0 2
#    B 4 0 0 1
#    C 0 0 0 5
#    D 2 1 5 0
```

Comment: "This feels like a bit of a hack, though" -- something which can be said about a great many good solutions in R. +1

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply @Paul. But actually, I still have a problem because I store my variables in a data frame.
 `df <- tribble(~var1,~var2,~score,data3$var1,data3$var2,data3$score)
df %>% mutate_if(is.character, factor, levels=c('data3$var1','data3$var2')) %>%  xtabs(score ~ var1 + var2,., drop.unused.levels = F) %>% '+'(., t(.))`

Comment: The way you are using `tribble` will result in list-columns. You can just use `data3 %>% mutate_if(is.character, factor, levels=c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')) %>% xtabs(score ~ var1 + var2, ., drop.unused.levels = F) %>% '+'(., t(.))`